# Any Idea how to do Session based authentication in laravel 5.3 using vue js and vue router

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource, vue-router

My biggest problem for now is the authentication

my head aches about this because im using api to fetch and send data to the server using vue

so ive tried doing the login thing with the AUTH middleware but it kept saying that Unauthorized even i logged in

so whats the problem with the authentication and how can i implement that session based authentication?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Laravel as an API, you'll likely want to do token-based authentication. The main idea is to use the 'api' guard (which uses the [TokenGuard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php) class), instead of the default 'web' guard (you can change this in `congif/auth.php`). This way Laravel will look for a Bearer token in the Authorization header in each request.

[This is a decent walk through](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51) to get started, though I'm sure there are many other good blog posts and tutorials out there.

EDIT:

Not sure if this is helpful, but here's an example using an automated test. In my ModelFactory, I have a user model with an `api_token` attribute which is set to a random (and unique) string of 60 characters. This is a simple test to make sure I can retrieve a list of users:

```
/** @test */
public function user_index_endpoint_returns_list_of_users()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $this->get('/users', array(
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $user->api_token
            ))
         ->assertResponseStatus(200)
         ->seeJsonStructure([
            'users'
         ]);
}
```

At the top of my `config/auth.php` file, I've set my default guard to 'api':

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Finally, in my routes file I've set up my users route to use the 'auth' middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index');
});
```

Because I've defined the 'api' middleware as my default, behind the scenes Laravel will use the TokenGuard class to try to authenticate my request. To do so, it will look for a bearer token in my request and compare that against the users table.

Comment: can you give a small snippet how to do that? this gave me head aches

Comment: I added to my answer with some example code. Hope it helps!